# difference base transformation and point transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

I am currently studying Computer Graphics, in which we made a graphics engine. While studying I came across something confusing regarding transformations. Rotations to be specific. In our course notes we are given how to get to the base transformations. These look like:

$$
   R_x(\phi)=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & \cos(\phi) & -\sin(\phi) & 0 \\
   0 & \sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi) & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

$$
R_y(\phi)=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   \cos(\phi) & 0 & \sin(\phi) & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   -\sin(\phi) & 0 & \cos(\phi) & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

$$
R_z(\phi)=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   \cos(\phi) & -\sin(\phi) & 0 & 0 \\
   \sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi) & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

However, these are not identical to the rotation formula's we had to use in our engines. The ones we had to use were

$$
   R_x(\phi)=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi) & 0 \\
   0 & -\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi) & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

$$
R_y(\phi)=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   \cos(\phi) & 0 & -\sin(\phi) & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   \sin(\phi) & 0 & \cos(\phi) & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

$$
R_z(\phi)=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi) & 0 & 0 \\
   -\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi) & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

Basically the sinus values all have the opposite sign. The given reason for this is: "In the course notes, base transformations are described. For our practicum we'll need point transformations. Therefore, use these and not the ones in the course notes."

I don't see why this is the case, what are the base transformations used for then? Why is only the sinus value affected by this?

Comment: The difference between the two is that the first rotation counterclockwise, and the second rotate clockwise. Not sure if this explains it though, but the direction of rotation is just convention.

Comment: `basic transformations` Are you sure that's not `base tansformations` instead? Rotating the "*base*" (i.e. axes) by $\,+\phi\,$ is equivalent to rotating the point by $\,-\phi\,$ indeed.

Comment: The difference lies in the point of view that you have about what the transformation does. In one case, the transformation “physically” moves points around. In the other case, points remain stationary but the coordinate system changes—all of the points get new labels.